# Angularjs Mongoose image persistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, mongoose

I'm trying to perform an image persistance into MongoDb database through a form in an angularjs application.

do i have to upload the image and after that perform the save operation to the database ? is there a working (inspiring) example ?

here is my code :

view.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="photo">Photo</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="photo" placeholder="Entrez la photo" ng-model-instant ng-model="profil.photo" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)">
```

my controller is the following:

```
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    for (var i in $scope.files) {
        fd.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i]);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", $scope.uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    // xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "/fileupload");
    $scope.progressVisible = true;
    xhr.send(fd);
    $scope.loader = true;
}

$scope.uploadComplete = function(evt) {
    /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
    $scope.affectSrcValue(angular.fromJson(evt.target.responseText));
}

function uploadFailed(evt) {
    console.log("There was an error attempting to upload the file.")
}

$scope.affectSrcValue = function(srcs) {
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.loader = false;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

to sumup i just need my image to be stored into MongoDB from my form and dont need to upload it !!
can anyone help with dao persistance for images ? into base64 ?

Comment: You will need to upload the image if you want to store it in MongoDB. To see some examples of how to store images in MongoDB using Mongoose check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/H-8JLNyivcc)